# Can i use fb.ui with FBML Canavas Applications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fbml, facebook-javascript-sdk

I know it's an easy question but I used to make Iframe inside my FBML and put some javascript SDK Codes , 
is there any way to use fb.ui instead the FBJS in fbml CANAVAS applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although FB.ui is a method of the Javascript SDK, you can still use FBJS to open a dialog. You can see available methods here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/#methods

However, I strongly recommend that you use an iframe application instead of FBML, as they are going to be deprecated soon by Facebook.